# How to write this Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm just a beginner and I am struggling to get this to work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

=IF(B2="","",COUNTIF($C:$C,$D2)=0,"No Penalty","Penalty")

Comment: Can you provide some data that your processing ?

Comment: What you are probably looking for is  Nested IF i.e. IF within an IF. Just put another IF with correct syntax before COUNTIF so that it becomes If B2= "" then "" , IF Countif then No Penalty , Penalty.

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(B2="","",IF(COUNTIF($C:$C,$D2)=0,"No Penalty","Penalty"))`

**Explanation:**

- If B2 is blank, the output of this formula is blank.
- If B2 is non-blank, then proceed to check the output of the COUNTIF equals, IF yes, then "No Penalty", else "Penalty"